# NoMethodError in Contact#new, issue with merging

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an issue with my form, I solved the first issue with help, but now I am getting new errors saying that I have an undefined method. Still learning RoR so if this sounds dumb please bear with me, thanks for the help in advanced.

Here is the code:

```
<h1>Create New Contact</h1>
<% form_for :contact, :url => { :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
  <p><label for="contact_first_name">First Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'first_name' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'last_name' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_address">Address:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'address' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_city">City:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'City' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_state">State:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'state' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_country">Country:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'country' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_phone">Phone:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'phone' %></p>

  <p><label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
  <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'email' %></p>

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>  

<p><%= link_to 'Back', { :action => 'index' } %></p>
```

And here is the error I'm getting,

```
NoMethodError in Contact#new

Showing C:/rails_projects/contactlist/app/views/contact/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `merge' for "first_name":String
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h1>Create New Contact</h1>
2: <% form_for :contact, :url => { :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
3:   <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
4:   <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'first_name' %></p>
5:   
6:   <p><label for="contact_last_name">Last Name:</label>
7:   <%= f.text_field 'contact', 'last_name' %></p>
Rails.root: C:/rails_projects/contactlist

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/contact/new.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_contact_new_html_erb___976580590_43916136'
app/views/contact/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_contact_new_html_erb___976580590_43916136'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Answer (score 0):

You text_field should just be

```
<%= f.text_field 'first_name' %></p>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.text_field 'contact', 'first_name' %></p>
```

The second argument is supposed to be a hash.

Comment: That did it, I had to add a route for that, and the book did not cover it. I don't know if this is intentional but It's a cool way to learn where it gives you code that won't work and then I have to figure out why it won't work. Only thing I'm noticing now is that the form doesn't appear in the web browser.

Comment: You will have to say `<%= form_for %>` intead of `<% form_for %>`